# Need AddThis Google plus button, but the old icon not the current one?

Tags: google-plus

I need to show Google + old button using AddThis, does anyone know a good way of doing that?

Comment: I think it belongs to [WebMasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), not Stackoverflow

Comment: Oh sorry! Maybe it does, but you know any solution?

Comment: No, I'm not, sorry. Just saying you've a better chances to get this question answered on WM.

Answer (score 3):

This is neither something that you can do with AddThis nor something that you should attempt to do on your own.

AddThis makes an active effort to comply with the [Google+ buttons policy](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/policy.html). This policy states that only the official icons can be used, which means that everyone who uses images of the button should keep their copies up to date.  Also, as a webmaster it's important to comply with policies like these when interacting with third party sites.